# Access users Google Analytics information with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

I've seen many websites which create infographics using Google Analytics (GA) stats.  The user is expected to do a third-party sign-up with their Google account.  The user then has to authorize the website to access their data.

I'd like to make a similar website, but can't figure out where to start.  My searching shows a ton of results for accessing your own GA account, but no instructions on how to leverage the user's GA account.

If someone can point to some tutorials, open source projects, or any resources to get me started, I would appreciate it.  My preferred language is C# asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this client-side you can use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/).

From the documentation site:

> The Google Analytics Embed API is a JavaScript library that allows you to easily create and embed a dashboard on a 3rd party website in a matter of minutes. It gives you a set of pluggable components that can work together to build complex tools, making it both simple and powerful at the same time.

And this demo site shows some examples of the Embed API in action:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/